DoEvents whilst a Time Delay Macro is running
I have a Macro in an excel sheet that selects a value in a slicer, I had a pivot which was converted to OLAP. When selecting a value in the slicer there is a short period of time where all the cells display '########' before the value is displayed. My trouble is. I have a macro which loops through these values and publishes them as PDF's. All PDF's as a result show "#######" in all the cells as when it is looping through the slicer values, it cannot delay the export. I have tried using the Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")) but this pauses the workbook and does not allow events to continue in the background. So I had a little check online and come across this little piece of code.
Sub WasteTime(Finish As Long)
 
    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long
 
    EndTick = GetTickCount + (Finish * 1000)
     
    Do
 
        NowTick = GetTickCount
        DoEvents
 
    Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
 
End Sub

Which is then called in the loop by WasteTime (10). The good news about this is, it appears to let me DoEvents, click in the sheet etc. The bad news about this is, it doesn't appear to end at all and all the values remain "#######"for well over 10 seconds. Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

A time delay is an incredibly unreliable way to achieve the result you're looking for. You're better off to look at what triggers your pdf creating macro and see if you can make that dependent on the completion of your conversion. Otherwise you could try set a loop in your macro that constantly checks if the values are ####### and only continues when it's not.

Before publishing place a loop try checking one of the necessary cells Text property. Something as Dim cel as range: Set cel = Range("your cell") followed by Do while Instr(cel.Text, "#") > 0 DoEvents Loop. Theoretically, it will exit the loop only after the respective cell value is resolved... Text property return what you show in the respective cell.

Try importing the ExcelAppState class and then create an instance in your macro with Dim app As New ExcepAppState. Then before you print to PDF call app.WaitForCalculations. See if this works
